# when are block scope variables allocated

Tags: c++, c, scope, stack

If I have a c function

```
int foo(int input)
{
    int x = 5;
    if( input == 0 ){
        int y = 6;
    } else {
        int z = 7;
    }
}
```

I know that that stack pointer is adjusted when we enter the function, and that makes space for the `int x` statement. And I know that `y` and `z` only exist within the scope of their respective blocks. But when and how is the space for them allocated?

Comment: AFAIK the compiler can select its own allocation strategy as long as it ensures the variables are only logically in scope when they should be.  Don't think the spec dictates specific allocation.

Comment: Those variables? By the time the optimizer is finished, *never*.

Comment: I'm aware that they would be optimized away. For the sake of brevity I didn't put in "... and do something..." I will in future question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's up to the compiler, as long as the space lasts for at least the lifetime of the variable.

Typically, space for all automatic variables in a function is allocated on the stack at the start of the function, and freed when the function returns. Some variables might be placed in registers, if they don't need to have an address. Your variables will probably not exist at all, since they are never used.

**Update:** As noted in the comments, C (but not yet C++) allows dynamically-sized local arrays. Obviously, space for these can't be allocated until the size is known.

Comment: Some compilers may allocate space for the variables when execution enters the scope that they are defined in, or when the definition is encountered.  This means that in the OP's example the Y and Z variables would be allocated when execution enters their respective statement blocks and not at the start of the function.

Comment: Not even because the assignements have no effects. So depending on the compiler, even the function itself might be completely removed.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Indeed, compilers could do that. But, on most platforms, that would be less efficient than a single allocation, so typically they don't.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Every C 1999 or 2011 implementation must support automatic (stack-like) allocation at arbitrary points, not just function entry. Consider `void foo(int x) { … int n = bar(x); char c[n]; … }`. The compiler cannot allocate space for `c` upon entry to `foo`, since the space required is unknown. An implementation should do allocation at the beginning of a function only for objects that both have a pre-computable size and are either used in every likely branch or are small.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Fair enough; I was thinking of C++, where there are no dynamically-sized objects (at least, not until next year). As you say, their allocation will have to be deferred until the size is known.

Answer (score 0):

```
int foo(int input)
{ // BLOCK 1
    int x = 5;
    if( input == 0 )
    { // BLOCK 2
        int y = input * (x + 6);
        // other code here
    }
    else
    { // BLOCK 3
        int z = input + x;
        // other code here
    }
}
```

The compiler is able to optimize much of this away, but the high level language rules are this:

`x` is valid in `BLOCK 1` and any sub-blocks (`BLOCK 2` and `BLOCK 3`).
`y` is valid only in `BLOCK 2`.
`z` is valid only in `BLOCK 3`.

The first pass the compiler makes will generally leave these rules in tact.  Subsequent passes will typically see that you are not using the variables (or optimize how they are used) and may move them around or not store them in memory at all (e.g. they may simply be put in a register), so trying to equate their scope in the high level language to how it will be optimized in assembly is a fool's errand.